# Как научиться делать анимацию джавасктриптом с помошью requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript

Привет.

Какие источники на русском языке являются лучшими, чтобы изучить анимацию с помощью метода requestAnimationFrame? Чтобы было разжевано. В ленджаваскрипт.ру читал про эту тему и ничего не понял.

setTimer и setInterval "проглатывают" кадры, хочется, чтоб анимация более плавной была, вот и решил разобраться с requestAnimationFrame.

Answer (score 1):

реализация `requestAnimationFrame` заботится сама о таких аспектах как плавность, процессорное время и т.д.

Например не воспроизводит анимацию когда пользователь находится на другой вкладке -> экономия процессорного времени

устанавливает оптимальное время наступления следующего кадра -> корректирвока анимации под разные машины

Comment: это я понимаю. хочу научиться ее использовать, а хорошего источника до сих пор не нашел (чтобы там все подробно разжевано было). везде все написано одинаково и непонятно - из одного места передрали

Comment: @Dimon что значит хочу научится его использовать ? что конкретно непонятно? вы умеете писать код на javascript ?

Comment: я не понимаю, как работает эта функция. вот, что это значит. подробного описания работы не нашел

Comment: @Dimon работает например [так](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671)